# iCloud not syncing all the contacts?

Tags: iphone

So, I saved my contacts from a .vcf file to my iPhone, then I created an iCloud account to back up my contacts. The iCloud only saved contacts that I had manually created in my iPhone but not the ones I save from the .vcf file. Help please!

Comment: there can be multiple contact "groups" on an iPhone, that could be a problem open contacts and see of the word "group" appears in the upper left corner.  Where are you importing the .vcf file?  I don't know how you would do this on the phone itself as your question implies, however using a computer and regular browser  log into icloud.com using the same appleID, click contacts, then try importing via the gear in the lower left.

Answer (score 1):

1. Got to Settings
2. Go to iCloud
3. Slide Contacts option to Off (You'll get a warning, make sure you choose to save the Contacts on your phone)
4. Close out of Settings
5. Wait 5 minutes or so
6. Go back to Settings\iCloud
7. Slide Contacts option to On (You'll get a message asking to merge Contacts, say yes)
8. Go to Settings\iCloud\Storage & Backup
9. Select Back Up Now

Answer (score 0):

Well , it will be somewhat complicated.

First you need ;

An Outlook 2010 on a PC and a GMAIL account.

In order to import outlook .vcf cards into ICLOUD, you will not be able to do it directly, you need to export from outlook, then import to google account, then export out of the google account as *vCard format (for importing into Apple Address Book or another application)* and there you will be able to get all your outlook contacts, exactly as they are, into your icloud account.

There are some limitations, as outlook does not let you EXPORT several vcards at the same time, and google does not let you import several vcards at the same time.

Here are the instructions to get this worked.

1. On outlook 2010, go to file, options, mail, and in the compose messages section select *plain text* from the dropdown box, then hit OK. THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT, for the next action to work.
2. Now go to CONTACTS, hit ctrl+a (will select all your contacts), then go up to the ribbon and on the SHARE section, where it reads Forward Contact, click on the drop down and select *As Business Cards* (if you don´t do step one, outlook will crash attempting to create images of the vcards for each contact on an email message).

3.If you did right, now you have a new email window opened, with all your vcards as attachment. select all the Vcards and copy.

4.Create a folder in C: and paste all those vcards in there.

5.Time to merge all vcards into a single one, for them to be uploaded into your GMAIL account, follow the instructions here

http://www.creativeworld9.com/2011/04/how-to-combine-all-vcf-files-to-single.htm 
l.

This link will teach you how to merge various VCF using the command prompt.

7.Once you managed to create one single .vcf files with all your contacts (don´t try to open it cause you will see nothing), go to your gmail account and import them. to do that, on the left upper corner of the screen, 3rd row, you’ll see the word *GMAIL*, click the dropdown there and select contacts.

Moving along the same row, go to *More*, click the dropdown and select *import contacts*, then select the VCF file and voilà….you contacts are now in GMAIL.

8.Now we will export the contacts select ALL contacts (if you have more than 100 contacts, you will need to do this in 3 or 4 pieces, selecting no more than 100 contacts to export) , then hit *more* and select *export contacts*. Use the last option, *vCard format (for importing into Apple Address Book or another application)*.

9. This will give you a VCF files with all the contacts, in a format that ICLOUD will accept with no issues, then just sync your idevice, and that is it.
   Do not try to export a CSV file from outlook to import into gmail, because it will dump most of the contact info into NOTES instead of the fields.

Hope it works.!!!